# Using Parallel MOSFETs as a simultaneous switch

Tags: mosfet, switches, parallel

I have searched quite a while, but using parallel MOSFETs to alleviate thermal issues and dividing currents seemed to be the critical issues for lots of people.

For me, I'm trying to use the parallel Nch MOSFETs(2N7002NXAK) to turn switch on and off at the same time. But it doesn't look like people are using parallel MOSFETs like this since I couldn't find any example.

I only have 1 GPIO to spare but 2 devices that I need to pull down when not in use. Is this not the normal way to use parallel MOSFETs at a switch?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: See: [Parallelling MOSFETS](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/para.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535744b4583f79). Also, be aware that HEXFETs in particular have (on occasion) similar problems as BJTs with respect to thermal runaway issues.

Comment: What is your load? Where are they connected? How about linking the data sheet for the mosfet?

Comment: Either R1 or R2 is redundant.